# Intersperse a column (or row) among many others

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

Is there any formula to intersperse a column or row among many others? For example, if I have rows A, B, C, D, E and F, let me keep A, B, A, C, A, D, A, E, A, F. I need to do this for a variable number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, why not:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY("♠"&A1&"♠"&A2:A6, , 999^99), "♠"))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much!! You always bring the best solutions.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no formula to *directly* achieve that.

You could make another sheet reflect those rows, e.g. set Sheet2 cell A1 to
`={Sheet1!1:1;Sheet1!2:2;Sheet1!1:1;Sheet1!3:3;Sheet1!1:1;Sheet1!4:4;Sheet1!1:1;Sheet1!5:5;Sheet1!1:1;Sheet1!6:6}`
That formula just grabs and stacks up rows: 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6.

If you're just looking to always be able to compare lower rows' values with row 1, you could get lower rows right next to row 1 by freezing row 1 and scrolling the rest. Or by hiding the rows. Freezing and hiding also work for columns.

Finally, you could try your hand at programming it to do that in [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview). The script could look at how many rows have data, insert a new row after each, and copy row 1 to the new blank rows.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to **@player0** answer, maybe you'll find it more readable:

```
={A1; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("♠"&A1&"♠"; A2:A6); "♠"))}
```